# Как убрать отступы у Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

Собственно как можно их убрать?
Что бы диалог заполнял полностью экран.
[image: Img]

Answer (score 1):

В стилях:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

В классе:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Спасибо.
А без использования setContentView, через setView никак ?

Comment: Не понимаю, вы через builder делаете? можно, если переопределить AlertDialog - устарел, я настоятельно рекомендую использовать DialogFragment, PopupWindow etc.